# Making AutoRest map classes to sub-objects in the response

Tags: swagger, autorest

I'm trying to write a client to a large non Swagger-documented API and thought that writing the swagger.json
for it and using AutoRest would be a good way to accomplish that. The case is that this API wraps each operation's
response data into a larger object with control information, like this:

```
{
    "resp_code": "SUCCESS",
    "caller_ref": "2016111116233156169531",
    "server_ref": "2016111116233189512798",

    "data": {
        "id": "idstring",
        "name": "nameString",
        "address": "addressString",
        ...
        }
}
```

Where "data" in this case would be a "Client" definition for us. Is there a way to define the 200 OK response 
schema and the definitions in the swagger.json file so that AutoRest would map this "data" to a Client class?

Comment: with "Client definition" you mean that you already *have* a class definition for the "data" property? So you want AutoRest to use *your* definition instead of generating its own (which is the default behavior)?

Comment: No, @olydis, please see answer below, thanks for commenting,

Answer (score 0):

In fact the answer is quite trivial, all I had to do is to write the "responses" object of the swagger file like this:

```
"responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "successful operation",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "data": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/Client"
                            }
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
```

Besides creating the `Client` definition. AutoRest generates code that retrieves the "data" object, giving access to the Client within.